# How can I have an image to the left of a text box with a grey background using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how can I have an to the left of a text box with a grey background behind the text using bootstrap? I'm trying to replicate this layout in the screenshot below by placing an image next to text box horizontally. Numbers three and four are images, six and five are text.

In terms of the text should I use?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Test</h1> 
    <p>Test123</p> 
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p> 
  <p>This is another text.</p> 
</div>
```

After I have to text in the correct place how can I place an image to the left of it like on the diagram below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is probably what you're looking for.  It sounds like you could use a primer in Bootstrap.  I would check out this link for w3schools.  It's free, they have concise, to the point explanations, it will get you up and running very quickly. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

In the meantime, start with this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: #aaa;"> <!-- You do not have to use inline styling.  Better to add this styling as a class -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- image here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <!-- text here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- image here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <!-- text here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```